# Qt: how to make a shadow to main window widget?

Tags: windows, qt, shadow

How to make a shadow to main window widget on windows using Qt?

Answer (score 2):

Applications normally do not create shadows, that is up to the window manager.  You could fake it by all sorts of evil hacks such as creating another borderless window that is the shadow color and put it under your main window.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to a related problem and many other qt questions can be found from the QT Center:
http://www.qtcentre.org

Direct path to one solution that at least looks pretty good is:
http://wiki.qtcentre.org/index.php?title=ARGB-Widgets